# Magento2 - How to save Product Review Programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, review, product-review

I'm trying to save review programmatically. This seems to be working but not totally and as it's using object manager; I would like to find the good proper way to handle this in Magento 2.

So basically my question is: How to replace this piece of code to make it "**clean**"

```
$stores=array(
    $this->block->getStoreId($this->block::STORE_CODE_PARTICULIER),
    $this->block->getStoreId($this->block::STORE_CODE_PRO)
);
$objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();

$_review = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\Review")
                ->setEntityPkValue($productId)
                ->setStatusId($statusReview)
                ->setTitle($reviewTitle)
                ->setDetail($reviewDetail)
                ->setEntityId(1)
                ->setStoreId($store_id)
                ->setStores($stores)
                ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                ->setNickname($customerNickName)
                ->save();
```

I wanted to find a repository for this review but seems like it doesn't exist?

Currently, this code works, but the behavior is odd (it's an import script...if I try to import one by one, my reviews are well created...but if I try to create more than 1, it will still only create one of them. That's why I suspect an unexpected behavior due to object manager being used.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Maybe I have to load the product and in fact, save the product more than the review itself?

Please let me know how you would handle this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then turns out the real explanation behind all that is the following :

```
$review = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\Review")
```

This call a singleton; which means, each time this is called, the same object was called which explain why all the time only my last entry was recorded.

So obviously here using a repository wasn't possible, but using the factory instead of the model was enough to fix it.

So quick fix was as I though removing the object manager and directly create a review factory instance.

Comment: Use create instead of get. Example 

 $review = $objectManager->create("Magento\Review\Model\Review")

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code and reference:

Here I have created this file in Magento root for sample add reviews.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo "HELLO STACK EXCHANGE";


$productId=5;
$customerId=13; //for Guest user $customerId=Null;
$customerNickName='STACK EXCHANGE';
$reviewTitle='STACK EXCHANGE';
$reviewDetail='STACK EXCHANGE';
$StoreId=1;
$title='STACK EXCHANGE';


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_review = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\Review")
->setEntityPkValue($productId)    //product Id
->setStatusId(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_PENDING)// pending/approved
->setTitle($reviewTitle)
->setDetail($reviewDetail)
->setEntityId(1)
->setStoreId($StoreId)
->setStores(1)
->setCustomerId($customerId)//get dynamically here 
->setNickname($customerNickName)
->save();


echo "Review Has been saved ";

echo "/////FOR SAVING RATING /////////
     ///////////////////////////////";

/* 
 $_ratingOptions = array(
     1 => array(1 => 1,  2 => 2,  3 => 3,  4 => 4,  5 => 5),   //quality
     2 => array(1 => 6,  2 => 7,  3 => 8,  4 => 9,  5 => 10),  //value
     3 => array(1 => 11, 2 => 12, 3 => 13, 4 => 14, 5 => 15),  //price 
     4 => array(1 => 16, 2 => 17, 3 => 18, 4 => 19, 5 => 20)   //rating
);*/

//Lets Assume User Chooses Rating based on Rating Attributes called(quality,value,price,rating)
$ratingOptions = array(
            '1' => '1',
            '2' => '7',
            '3' => '13',
            '4' => '19'
);      
        
foreach ($ratingOptions as $ratingId => $optionIds) 
{     
       $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\Rating")
                     ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                     ->setReviewId($_review->getId())
                     ->addOptionVote($optionIds, $productId);
            
}
echo  "Latest REVIEW ID ===".$_review->getId()."</br>";     
$_review->aggregate();
echo "Rating has been saved submitted  successfully";

?>
```

REF URL: https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-product-review-rating-programatically-in-magento2/

I hope this will help.

Comment: This is the code i'm already using if you look at the question^^...I want to avoid using object manager.

Comment: Then I would suggest, please create a custom module and add the required class in the constructor. Please review the reference URL.